# How make a port appear open with an nmap scan

Tags: networking, netcat, nmap, port

To avoid someone knowing which port are open on my machine, I thought it would useful to open all unused port so that the nmaper is unable to identify which port are really open.

**How make a port appear open with an `nmap` scan**

Comment: Something needs to open/listen to the port ; https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/270647/117549 is an example, but you seem instead to be asking how you could have something listening to ~65,000 ports, correct?

Comment: Related question: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/399626/why-is-kali-linux-so-hard-to-set-up-why-wont-people-help-me

Answer (score 1):

You have got labrea for people scanning your network IP addresses, have not tested it for a good while now.

> labrea - Honeypot for incoming IP connection attempts
>
> labrea creates virtual machines for unused IP addresses in the
>   specified block of IP addresses. LaBrea sits and listens for ARP
>   "who-has" requests.
>
> When an ARP request for a particular IP goes unanswered for longer
>   than its "rate" setting (default: 3 seconds), labrea crafts an ARP
>   reply that routes all traffic destined for the IP to a "bogus" MAC
>   address. labrea sniffs for TCP/IP traffic sent to that MAC address and
>   then responds to any SYN packet with a SYN/ACK packet that it creates.

To install it in Debian, do:

```
sudo apt-get install labrea
```

As for answering in some designated common ports, and providing alerts, you have got [psad](https://hackertarget.com/psad-port-scan-detection-in-ubuntu-linux/), though as far as I remembered it was not about listening all ports.

You can always run honeypots, though I have not tested them for a good while.

Nevertheless, and entering the realm of my opinion, I prefer to drop all connections to unused ports, the less services that are exposed to the outside, the less avenues for attacks.

Comment: Off topic, further references: "TCP/IP Illustrated, vol I - the protocols", 2nd edition, Stevens et al;

Answer (score 0):

On Linux, you can use `iptables`'s [`socket`](https://manpages.debian.org/iptables/iptables-extensions.8#socket) match to have `iptables` know if a `TCP` port is in use. Combined with the [xtables-addons](http://xtables-addons.sourceforge.net/)'s [`TARPIT`](https://manpages.debian.org/xtables-addons-common/xtables-addons.8#TARPIT) target (also using LaBrea's concepts) this can make look open any *unused* `TCP` port automatically, while leaving actual open ports working as usual. For `UDP` there's probably not much difference between an open port not answering and a dropped port so I'm not talking about it anymore (just drop udp by default).

Rules:

```
iptables -N openclosed
iptables -A openclosed -p tcp -m socket --nowildcard -j RETURN
iptables -A openclosed -p tcp -j TARPIT --honeypot
iptables -I INPUT -j openclosed
```

Caveats: every connection makes a conntrack entry used by netfilter. This solution can thus make a lot of conntrack ressources become used. Bear this in mind when the system is receiving an attack rather than a scan. While `TARPIT` can be used without netfilter (using `NOTRACK`), I'm not sure `socket` can, and anyway this can't be kept as simple as above. Adding the `--honeypot` option to `TARPIT` makes it cheaper for the scan if not sending data, but also for netfilter; feel free to remove it. Also `--nowildcard` might or might not be suitable for router usage (but it's ok anyway for a local usage in the `INPUT` chain).